# Deploying a WAR file to iPlanet with Class-Path specified

Tags: java, deployment, manifest, war, iplanet

I develop a Java web application and deploy it on Oracle iPlanet 7. Currently, I deploy the library dependencies with the application, i.e. in WEB-INF/lib. What I would like to do is deploy the application in a WAR file, without the JAR files, and specify the library dependencies in the MANIFEST.MF file.

I think I understand what I'm supposed to do. I want my JAR files in a separate directory. The MANIFEST.MF file needs a line like this:

```
Class-Path: lib/jar1.jar lib/jar2.jar
```

Then, the directory containing the WAR file needs to look like this:

```
webapp.war
lib/
    jar1.jar
    jar2.jar
```

The problem that I'm running into with iPlanet 7 is that when I deploy the WAR file, iPlanet unpacks it and places the app in another directory. I end up with a directory like this:

```
webapp.war
server-name/
    webapp/
        ...
lib/
    jar1.jar
    jar2.jar
```

Is there a way to tell iPlanet not to unpack my WAR file?

Comment: If the JARs aren't in the WAR, then they should be on the app server /lib level.  I don't know any Java EE app server where you'd do what you're suggesting.

Comment: Oracle iPlanet, to my knowledge, is not an app server. It's just a web server/servlet container.